# Not able to display the listView

Tags: java, listview, javafx, fxml

I am trying to make an application, I want to display the list of items using list view in javaFX.I tried everything but it is not letting me display anything.

Main.java

```
package application;
    
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Main.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Song Library");
            
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

ReadDisplaySongList.java

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

public class ReadDisplaySongList  implements Initializable
{
    static ArrayList<SongListObj> song_list = new ArrayList<SongListObj>();
    
    @FXML
    private ListView <String> song_Artist_List;
    
    
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1)
    {
        
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ReadDisplaySongList.fxml"));
        ReadDisplaySongList controller = new ReadDisplaySongList();
        loader.setController(controller);
        

        try {
            
            Parent root = loader.load();
            
            List<String> items = Arrays.asList("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3");
            song_Artist_List.getItems().setAll(items);
            
            //song_Artist_List.getItems().add("Apple");
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
            
    }
    
    
    

}
```

ReadDisplaySongList.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="524.0" prefWidth="578.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <BorderPane layoutX="345.0" layoutY="29.0" prefHeight="445.0" prefWidth="420.0">
         <left>
            <ListView fx:id="song_Artist_List" prefHeight="348.0" prefWidth="389.0"  BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
         </left>
      </BorderPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Main.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Circle?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="529.0" prefWidth="626.0" style="-fx-background-color: #051622;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <fx:include source="ReadDisplaySongList.fxml" />
  
   <Circle fill="#04402b" layoutX="34.0" layoutY="14.0" radius="100.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
   <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="37.0" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="158.0" text="Song Library" textFill="BEIGE">
      <font>
         <Font name="Berlin Sans FB Demi Bold" size="23.0" />
      </font>
   </Label>
   
</AnchorPane>
```

I tired loading the fxml file to the java class, made sure that I have given the fx:id to the listview.

Comment: Where is `Main.fxml's` `Controller? Why are you doing `FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ReadDisplaySongList.fxml"));
        ReadDisplaySongList controller = new ReadDisplaySongList();
        loader.setController(controller);` inside of `ReadDisplaySongList`?

Comment: My guess is that you want to load `ReadDisplaySongList.fmxl` in `Main.java` and remove `FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ReadDisplaySongList.fxml"));
        ReadDisplaySongList controller = new ReadDisplaySongList();
        loader.setController(controller);
        

        try {
            
            Parent root = loader.load();` from `ReadDisplaySongList `.

Comment: I am having different FXML file for everything, then calling them again in one single fxml file.

Comment: You need to decide if you are going to use `<fx:include>` or if you are going to load `ReadSongDisplayList.fxml` in the controller. If the former, you need to specify a `fx:controller` attribute in the fxml so the controller is created. If the latter, you need to remove the `<fx:include>` and then actually place the result of loading the fxml in the scene graph somewhere. Right now you are loading the fxml twice, once with `<fx:include>`, but that time you have no controller associated with it, and once in the `initialize()` method, but that time you don’t display it.

Comment: Study the section on [nested controllers](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers).